# How to increase the speed of asking questions for Flash Card Template based quizzes?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assist-api

I am trying to make a game that involves rapid fire of questions and quick responses to them. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the speed of the flash card template, although you could create a new project using Actions on Google and Dialogflow to have a larger amount of control over the conversational flow.